# User Online Remains 1

Tags: php, session, mysqli

Everything is working and communicating with the database but regardless of how many users are online it stays 1

I have helper functions I created for num rows and query

> Online Users

```
function users_online(){


    $session = session_id();
    $time = time();
    $time_out_in_seconds = 60;
    $time_out = $time = $time_out_in_seconds;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users_online WHERE session = '$session'";
    $result = query($sql);
    $count = row_count($result);

    if ($count == NULL) {

        $sql= "INSERT INTO users_online(session, time) VALUES ('$session','$time')";
        query($sql);
    } else {

        $sql= "UPDATE users_online SET time = '$time' WHERE session = '$session'";
        query($sql);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users_online WHERE time > '$time_out'";    
    return $count_user = row_count($result);
}
```

> DB Config Helper functions

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'danger_db');

function row_count($result)
{
    return mysqli_num_rows($result);
}

function escape($string)
{
    global $connection;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $string);
}

function query($query)
{
    global $connection;
    return mysqli_query($connection, $query);
}

function confim($result)
{
    global $connection;
    if (! $result) {
        die("QUERY FAILED" . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
}

function fetch_array($result)
{
    global $connection;
    return mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}
```

> Database Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_online` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `session` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=31 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users_online`
--

INSERT INTO `users_online` (`id`, `session`, `time`) VALUES
(30, 'n3kppn4lp0n9h4gdm7a6rh84b2', 1452969896),
(29, 'mqhrkr2b3f2rga1vhqh4t6pe23', 1452969689),
(28, 'dpg2nmsrvsvottj9k7ot1gvcm6', 1452969893);
```

Comment: In your update users function, you're calling `$sql($result, ...`) - `$sql` is the variable you just created for your query, so it's almost certainly not doing what you think it means. Probably you intend `query($result, ...` instead

Comment: Where are you starting your session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $time = time();
    $time_out_in_seconds = 60;
    $time_out = $time = $time_out_in_seconds;
```

What are you trying to do here? You are setting `time_out` ***and*** `$time` to be equal to `$time_out_in_seconds`. So you're setting all three values to `60` static value.

Then later in the code you are saving the value `60` into the database and then you are calling the `time > '$time_out'` SQL so you're setting the user online to always being 60 and then always asking the database to return the rows that are *greater than* 60.

### **Solution**

Replace the above code with:

```
    $time = time();
    $time_out_in_seconds = 60;
    $time_out = $time - $time_out_in_seconds;
    //edit this will further down the page show all users who 
    //updated within the last 60 seconds.
```

This will now mean that your SQL query will check the time of the session *against the current time* as well as updating sessions *with the current time* as well. This should give you better results.

You  also have poor coding at the end of your code here:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users_online WHERE time > '$time_out'";    
return $count_user = row_count($result);
```

The return takes the value and passes it back to your calling script, this value is the value you want to give the number of users online, but what is the value of return? It is made up of `row_count($result)`. What is `$result`? The last `$sql` row is the one you need to get the results from, but this row has no relation to the result variable.

You have missed a line and so you need to reinsert the line `$result = query($sql);` so:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users_online WHERE time > '$time_out'";    
$result = query($sql);
return row_count($result);
}
```

This will now give you the numeric value for the number of rows returned of currently online users, as the result of the function `users_online();`

Comment: I'm trying to show users online I took a course online and this was exactly how the instructor did it.

Comment: @Phpfreak regardless of what your instructor did, is this above what you intend to be happening in your SQL queries? It doesn't look like it, as it would not give you a true result.

Comment: @Phpfreak I have added a solution for you. Take a look.

Comment: Martin its updating in the database but it still seems to be not counting :-(

Comment: @Phpfreak I spotted a missed line in your code. You need to be far more careful copy and pasting and please take time to read and establish the flow of were each variable gets its data from. I have updated my answer for you.

Comment: Martin I used your suggestion and now the result is 0 I have updated the top original post to give you a little more info

Comment: What result were you expecting to get?  @Phpfreak

Comment: the result I was expecting is if 2 users are logged in it will say 2

Comment: Are the correct values in your database? is your `time` column the correct column type (int,10)?

Comment: I am trying to show how many users are online if 53 people are online and I login it should say there are 54 people online

Comment: Martin I added the database at the top

Comment: Ahh of course, I've got it, what it is is the final `$sql` is checking all the time stamps that are more recent than the current time which is of course impossible (or at least, not sensible). I will update my answer now... @Phpfreak

Comment: I have edited my answer, the time it checks should be time *more recent* than time value `current - 60 seconds`, obviously you can adjust this to whatever you feel appropriate. @Phpfreak

Comment: @Phpfreak how often to users run the `users_online` function? Every page? It may be worth increasing the time pause from 60 seconds to 180 or 300 even, showing all users online within the last 5 minutes, for example.

Comment: Martin thank you sooooo much! I am bald now from pulling my hair out lol

Comment: Awesome. Glad we solved it! And I think your instructor did a typo on their original files it should have been a minus `-` rather than a second equals `=`. @Phpfreak